# No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

spring boot 2.1.1 can not read yml config to LinkedHashMap

this is my class

I've provided get and set functions. But it doesn't work.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("shiro")
public class ShiroConfiguration {
    private LinkedHashMap<String, String> filterChainDefinitions;
}
```

this is my config

```
shiro:
  filterChainDefinitions:
    /**: origin
```

this is error message

```
Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'shiro.filter-chain-definitions' to java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>:

    Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>]

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

Comment: were you able to solve it

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

@ConfigurationProperties can't map LinkedHashMap from you properties. You have to use SpEL which is not supported as mentioned [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1768)

To solve your issue could update the configuration by adding @Value annotation eg.:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
public class ShiroConfiguration {

  @Value("#{${shiro.filter-chain-definitions}}")
  private LinkedHashMap<String, String> filterChainDefinitions;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The special characters(`/`, `*`) in the key are throwing the binding off. Map keys with special characters need to be surrounded with square brackets. The below should work:

```yaml
shiro:
  filterChainDefinitions:
    '[/**]': origin
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use configuration properties. Ex

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "shiro")
class YourComponent {

    private HashMap<String, Integer> filterChainDefinitions;

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getFilterChainDefinitionsta() {
        return filterChainDefinitions;
    }

    public void setFilterChainDefinitions(HashMap<String, Integer> filterChainDefinitions) {
        this.filterChainDefinitions= filterChainDefinitions;
    }

}
```

Comment: I've provided get and set functions. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you add `@EnableConfigurationProperties`?

Comment: I didn't do it， Except map other is normal

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with the way you are calling the configuration property.

Have you tried renaming your property path:

`filterChainDefinitions` to `filter`

and

`private LinkedHashMap<String, String> filterChainDefinitions;`
to
`private LinkedHashMap<String, String> filter;`?

Such errors could also occur sometimes due to a wrong encoding or escaping but this doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Rename the variable , It does not work too, spring boot 1.5.* is no problem。

Answer (score 0):

Try using block mappings like this:

```
shiro:
  filterChainDefinitions:
    {}
```

When the value of shiro.filterChainDefinitions is empty it will be interpreted as an empty string. There's no way for YAML to know it's supposed to be a LinkedHashMap. Use an empty block mapping to represent the empty Hashmap.

From the [docs:](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2798057)
*A Block mapping is a series of entries, each presenting a key: value pair.*